# I Have A Problem With Playing Multiple Audios At Once

Tags: java, audio

```
package me.Warrior;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.FloatControl;
public class SoundPlayer {
    static URL path=null;
    static AudioInputStream inputStream; 
    public static Clip clip;
    public static synchronized void Play(final String url,float Volume) { 
          new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
              try {
                  clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                  URL resource = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(url);
                path=resource;
                inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(path);
                clip.open(inputStream);
                setVolume(Volume,clip);
                clip.start();
              } catch (Exception e) {
              }
            }
          }).start();
        }

    public static void setVolume(float Volume,Clip clip) {
         FloatControl gainControl = 
                    (FloatControl) clip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
         float dB=(float)(Math.log(Volume)/Math.log(10)*20);
                gainControl.setValue(dB);
    }
}
```

**So i play lots of audios in my Game and i think there is a problem whereas if i play two audios at the same sixtieth of a second it pops an Error and Freezes the Game for half a second

1. Can i somehow determine when the clip starts playing, so i can stop the next clip
   (I want to see when the clip starts Playing, not When it is Playing)
   (But that would be interesting for me as well)
2. Is there any better way to Play Audio than this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clips were NOT designed to be opened and started at the same time. They won't even start playing until the entire file is loaded from disk. I'm guessing if you try to play two at virtually the same time with the code you are showing, the file-loading lag issues will compound.

What you can (and should) do instead is to initialize your Clips beforehand, including opening them, and hold them in memory, ready to go. When it is time to play them, you should only execute the following:

```
public void playMyAudioFX() {
    myAudioFX.setFramePosition(0);
    myAudioFX.start();
}
```

By setting the frame position to the start, you can re-use the `Clip` without having to load it over and over.

But if you don't want to use up your memory holding audio, then use `SourceDataLine` for playback. Only one buffer's worth of data is loaded from disk before the `SourceDataLine` starts playing (as opposed to waiting for the entire file to load).

Neither of these file types works well with concurrent playback (playing it twice or more at the same time), but if you do the above correctly, the sounds should start off fine. If there are still problems, or if you are unhappy with how clunky the MASTER_GAIN line is, there are a couple simple libraries to try. One is called [TinySound](https://github.com/finnkuusisto/TinySound), the other [AudioCue](https://github.com/philfrei/AudioCue). I'm partial to the latter (since I wrote it) and it does handle concurrent playback and has much finer-grained real-time control for volume than `Clip`.

This is a really common issue, and a lot of the reason is that the Java tutorials on audio are difficult to read, so people miss these important details. I guess many other volunteer tutorial writers don't do a good job of emphasizing best practices, are content to just get a sound playing and leave it at that.

EDIT: rereading your question--There is a class called a `LineListener` that can receive notifications as to when a `Clip` starts or stops if you want to pursue that aspect further.

Also, if you are getting actual error messages, please post them! That will help with determining causes and solutions.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that, I will try

Comment: and yea, I don't mind wasting a bit of memory, this is a small game after all

Comment: so that means i should pre Open/Load all the audios and start playing it from the start when necessary (because loading takes lots of time, that's why my game freezes, if i understood correctly)

Comment: Hard to say for sure, but from what you described, this seems to me like it could be the issue. You'll have to try it and see if it helps. Clips were designed to be held open in memory, so you'll be changing to a better practice. I'd consider making the FloatControl a class-level field variable instead of local also. But it's no where near as costly to reinitialize that as to reinitialize a Clip. Also, I added a couple of minor edits, pertaining to tracking audio events and error messages.